# Qt >= 5.14: How to disable AAB creation in QtCreator (generate only armv7)

Tags: android, qt, qt-creator

Is there a way to pass arguments to `androiddeployqt` in QtCreator? I would like to generate only `armv7` APK file. `--aab` command line argument would do the trick as stated [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment-android.html#command-line-arguments) but I don't know how to pass arguments through QtCreator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QtCreator 4.11 or newer is needed. It's also recommended to remove the `.pro.user` file that is in the same folder as your `.pro` file (usually the root folder of the app).
In the **Projects** panel the new QtCreator has the possibility to enable/disable `.aab` creation under the **Advanced Actions** section
[image]

Another important configuration is the ABI selection under **Build Steps -> qmake** (click on Details). This will save you quite some compile time.

[image]